# Servicefabric cluster certificate rollover and Add-AzServiceFabricClusterCertificate

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a servicefabric cluster deployed (uses thumbprint not commonname), whose cluster certificate is close to expiring. I am a bit confused about the process for adding new certificate and making the rollover.

There is this article that sheds light on it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-rollover-cert-cn

It mentions that using commonnames makes the process easier, but doesnt mention how commonname based rollover is easier?

I have also seen this command
Add-AzServiceFabricClusterCertificate - This can create the certificate in Keyvault and update servicefabric cluster too.

My questions are:

1. Is this a replacement for process described in the article above?
2. Can this be used for certificate rollover?
3. Once the new certificate is added is the rollover automatic?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicefabric/add-azservicefabricclustercertificate?view=azps-2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

An update. This command (`Add-AzServiceFabricClusterCertificate`) did the trick. It updated the servicefabric cluster/vm scaleset and added a secondary certificate. I was able to swap the secondary and primary certificate as a second operation.

Comment: How did you swap the secondary and primary certificates? I have a cert already installed on the reverse proxy that i want to now use for the cluster, but can't figure out how to make the swap